# 'RUN' in Linux Mint wont work

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint, zenity

when i double click on an executable file, it wont run after i click RUN. i have tried it with a couple of .sh files and some downloaded software, does anyone know why?

a particular .sh file i need to run is a zenity menu. When i try in terminal it just says

```
sh: Can't open TaskC.sh
```

thats after i use

```
sh TaskC.sh
```

in the file i have used the properties to make it executable and used

```
chmod 755 TaskC.sh
```

1. Does anyone know how i can run it without the terminal?
2. Anyone know how i can get the .sh to run in the terminal?

my code just incase thats the problem

```
#!/bin/bash
#GUI for TaskB menu
chmod 755 TaskC.sh
    temp='mktemp -t temp.XXXXXX'
    temp2='mktemp -t temp2.XXXXX'

function software {
sudo get-apt install gparted gnome-desk-utility
zenity --text-info --title "Install Software" --filename=$temp
--width 750 --height 10}

function create {
touch > Desktop/CET103Demo.txt
zenity --text-info --Title "Create CET103Demo.txt" --filename=$temp
--width 300 --height 500}

function delete {
rm Desktop/CET103Demo.txt
zenity --text-info --title "Remove CET103Demo.txt" --filename=$temp
--width 300 --height 500}

function search {
grep -H -r "BASH" /home/mintuser/.profile
zenity --text-info --Title "Search BASH" --filename=$temp
--width 300 --height 500}

while [ 1 ]
do

zenity --list --radiolist --title "TaskC Menu" --column "Select" --column "Menu     Selection"
FALSE "Install Software" FALSE "Create file" FALSE "Remove File" FALSE "Search BASH"   False  "Exit"   > $temp2
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
break fi
    selection ='cat $temp2'
    case $selection in
    "Install Software")
        software;;
    "Create File")
        create;;
    "Remove File")
        delete;;
    "Search BASH")
        search;;
    Exit)
break ;; *)
zenity --info "Sorry, invalid selection" esac
done $
```

many thanks

Comment: Did you consider not running your program thru a graphical interface, but running it on a terminal ?

Comment: i need it to be GUI, its part of an assignment, i have a terminal menu that i need to make a GUi for

Comment: You should put the ending brace of your functions on a separate line. In bash, there needs to be whitespace before the ending brace (a newline satisfies this condition), and if it's not on it's own line, the command needs to end with a semi-colon. See [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping). `break fi` is also wrong -- did you have trouble cut-and-paste-ing your code?

Comment: If your script is actually a bash script (if you use bash-specific commands), don't invoke it with `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `./TaskC.sh`

You have to be in the same directory than the script, of course. If you want to execute it from anywhere, you need to add it to your PATH (see KevinDTimm's answer)

Comment: **You have to be in the same directory than the script**. Also POSIX systems are case sensitive, e.g. `TaskC.sh` is **NOT** `taskc.sh`.

Comment: i got it to run using sh ~/Desktop/TaskC.sh

Comment: Then, **again**, you were not in the same directory than the script.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem in your terminal window:

The problem is that your PATH is incorrect, you have to include the current directory

first fix is to run `sh ./TaskC.sh` - this has to be done each time you run something in the current directory

second is to set your PATH like `export PATH=$PATH:.` - this will fix it for the current invocation of your shell.  Add that line to .bashrc for it to be set every time you log in

Comment: where do i find my .bashrc? i have tried whereis .bashrc and ls -la but it seems i dont have one.

Comment: nevermind, i ran 'nano ~/.bashrc' and i added 'export PATH=$PATH:.